# Creation of folders in Windows through Java in PLSQL

Tags: java, function, plsql, oracle11g, directory

I am trying to have my Oracle 11g database create folders at the file system level (Windows OS).

This is the code I executed on my schema ABC_DEF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED createFolder AS
public class FolderManagement {
   public static java.lang.String createFolder(java.lang.String folderPath) {
       java.lang.String folderCreated = “false”;
       try {
          java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(folderPath);
          if(folder.exists() == true){
             folderCreated = “true”; // folder already exists and is usable
          }
          else {
             folder.mkdirs(); // If the parent folder exists, create all necessary subdirectories
             if(folder.exists() == true){
                 folderCreated = “true”;
             }
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           folderCreated = “false. Error message [” + e.getMessage() + “]”;
       }
       return folderCreated;
   }
};
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createFolder(folderPath IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME ‘FolderManagement.createFolder(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String’;
/
```

Then, I have an Oracle package as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ABC_DEF.FILE_UTILITIES AS
    parentFolder CONSTANT VARCHAR2(4000) := ‘H:\Oracle logs’;
    FUNCTION createDirectory(fullPathToFolder IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ABC_DEF.FILE_UTILITIES AS

    FUNCTION createDirectory(fullPathToFolder IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    folderCreated BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    returnedValue VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
       SELECT createFolder(fullPathToFolder)
       INTO returnedValue
       FROM DUAL;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Returned value from folder creation is [’ || returnedValue || ‘]’);
       IF UPPER(returnedValue) = ‘TRUE’ THEN
           folderCreated := TRUE;
       END IF;
       RETURN folderCreated;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           folderCreated := FALSE;
           RETURN folderCreated;
    END;

END;
/
```

Now, on my SYS (with SYSDBA permissions) schema, I have executed the below command, which should give the ABC_DEF schema permissions to read/write/delete files and folders at any level of recursion for the folder “H:\Oracle logs”.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_JAVA.GRANT_PERMSSION(
     grantee => ‘ABC_DEF’,
     permission_type => ‘SYS:java.io.FilePermission’,
     permission_name => ABC_DEF.FILE_UTILITIES.parentFolder || ‘\-’, —- Should grant recursive permissions to any subfolder and any file located in any subfolder
     permission_action => ‘read,write,delete’
  );
END;
/
```

Back to my ABC_DEF schema, when I try to execute the below code, I get an exception from the Java code:

```
DECLARE
subfolderToCreate VARCHAR2(4000) := ‘\2019\November’;
folderWasCreated BOOLEAN := FALSE;
fullFolderPath VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   fullFolderPath := FILE_UTILITIES.parentFolder || subfolderToCreate;
   folderWasCreated := FILE_UTILITIES.createDirectory(fullFolderPath);
   IF folderWasCreated = TRUE THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Folder was created.’);
   ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Folder was not created.’);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Folder wasn’’t created. Exception message [’ || SQLERRM || ‘]’);
END;
```

I get the following error:

```
Permission (java.io.FilePermission H:\Oracle logs\2019\November read) has not been granted to ABC_DEF. The PL/SQL to grant this is dbms_java.grant_permission(‘ABC_DEF’, ‘SYS:java.io.FilePermission’, ‘H:\Oracle logs\2019\November’, ‘read’)
```

The same error appears if I use the parent folder (which already exists at the file system level).

Any ideas as to why and how to resolve it?

EDIT: Adding information as per request

The query

```
SELECT *
FROM DBA_JAVA_POLICY
WHERE GRANTEE = ‘ABC_DEF’AND TYPE_NAME LIKE ‘%File%’;
```

Shows one row for folder ‘H:\Oracle logs\-’ under the NAME column is ENABLED for actions that are ‘read,write,delete’.

In regards to the H: drive, it’s a physical drive and not a network drive.

In regards to the folder settings at Windows level, the “Oracle logs” folder already exists at the Windows level and the access is full control for “Everyone”.

Comment: Lots of extraneous information here.  The error message seems to tell you exactly what you need to do.  Q: Have you looked at the permissions for "ABC_DEF" after you executed "DBMS_JAVA.GRANT_PERMSSION"?  Do you see *EVERY* permission mentioned in the error message "granted"?  Q: What about the *windows* user that "ABC_DEF" maps to?  Q: Does "H:" happen to be a network share?  If so, does "ABC_DEF" have *windows domain permissions* to read/write those directories?

Comment: I added answers to your questions. I disagree on the extraneous information though. I added the details about the java part and the stored procedure that calls it just in case I could’ve messed up that part. Wanted to be thorough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it as shown below:

- I removed the permissions from the Oracle side by running this command as SYS:

  ```
  DECLARE
      permissionNumber NUMBER(35);
  BEGIN
      SELECT SEQ
      INTO permissionNumber
      FROM DBA_JAVA_POLICY
      WHERE TYPE_NAME LIKE ‘%File%’ AND GRANTEE = ‘ABC_DEF’;
      DBMS_JAVA.disable_permission(permissionNumber);
      DBMS_JAVA.delete_permission(permissionNumber);
  END;
  /
  ```

Then I executed the below command, still as SYS:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_JAVA.GRANT_PERMISSION(
      GRANTEE           => ‘ABC_DEF’,
      PERMISSION_TYPE   => ‘java.io.FilePermission’
      PERMISSION_NAME   => ABC_DEF.FILE_UTILITIES.parentFolder || ‘\-’,
      PERMISSION_ACTION => ‘execute’
  );
END;
/

BEGIN
   DBMS_JAVA.GRANT_PERMISSION(
      GRANTEE           => ‘ABC_DEF’,
      PERMISSION_TYPE   => ‘java.io.FilePermission’
      PERMISSION_NAME   => ABC_DEF.FILE_UTILITIES.parentFolder || ‘\-’,
      PERMISSION_ACTION => ‘write’
  );
END;
/

BEGIN
   DBMS_JAVA.GRANT_PERMISSION(
      GRANTEE           => ‘ABC_DEF’,
      PERMISSION_TYPE   => ‘java.io.FilePermission’
      PERMISSION_NAME   => ABC_DEF.FILE_UTILITIES.parentFolder || ‘\-’,
      PERMISSION_ACTION => ‘read’
  );
END;
/
```

Then, I did the same at the file system level on Windows: removed permissions from folder settings and re-added them.

Finally, I re-ran the code that was giving me an exception. It succeeded. There is still one case, which is a false negative, where the exception is thrown and that is if the subFolderToCreate variable is empty.

I also noticed that it didn’t work immediately for some reason. It needed a few minutes in order for it to work...

Comment: I think you could have success since first attempt, I tried to grant at once all permissions without issue,s the key was re-login in order to have the grants active.